# Running cucumber from command line but need to run from IDE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automation, cucumber, rubymine

I have currently joined a project which is executing the cucumber tests from the command line using this command:

```
bundle exec cucumber file.feature type='browser' browser='chrome'
```

I want to be able to run this in rubymine, however, When I try to run it fails and I believe its due to it needs to know which file to run, which browser to start etc. I want to get it running in rubymine for the built in debugging breakpoints etc. How would I go about this? Its something I haven't done before?

Thanks.

Comment: Does RubyMine have the option to set "Run Configurations", like IntelliJ?

Comment: have you tried: rails s in the project root / folder from another terminal before running the command in the ruby mine console?  Have you tried using pry to get breakpoints even when running from the command line?